# Remove empty files and save a list of deleted files

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-findutils

I need a script that removes all empty files and writes a list of deleted files to a text file.

Deleting files works. Unfortunately, the listing does not work.

```
find . -type f -empty -print -delete
```

I tried something like this:

```
-print >> test.txt
```

Comment: Works for me. What output do you get?

Comment: @joanis Yes, it works. I get the output. But I want to send it to a file. This means - each deleted file -> its name saved in the test.txt file

Comment: Ah, interesting problem: when I redirect the output to a file in `.`, the command itself deletes it before anything gets written to it, so it goes missing. Try `find . -type f -empty -print -delete > ../output`

Answer (score 5):

When I redirect the output of your command to a file in `.`, it gets delete by the find command before anything is written to it, since it is empty.

To solve this, make sure the output file is not empty at the beginning, or save it elsewhere:

```
find . -type f -empty -print -delete > ../log
```

or

```
date > log
find . -type f -empty -print -delete >> log
```

or, adapted from @DanielFarrell's comment:

```
find . -type f -empty -a -not -wholename ./log  -print -delete > log
```

The added `-a -not -wholename ./log` excludes `./log` from the find operation.

Comment: Or exclude with `-not -name log`

Comment: Perhaps `{ date; find . -type f -empty -print -delete; } > log` would be useful to log the timestamp of the action.

Comment: @glennjackman That might seem like a good idea, but I wonder if log might still be empty when find got to it, because of output buffering in the pipe. `date > log; find ... >> log` would reliably work, however.

Comment: Right, good point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use -exec option with rm command instead of -delete.

```
find . -type f -emtpy -exec rm --verbose {} \; >> logfile.txt
```

logfile.txt:

```
removed './emptyfile1'
removed './emptyfile0'
```

Or you can use pipes and xargs for a more clean output:

```
find . -type f -empty | xargs ls | tee -a logfile.txt | xargs rm
```

This will give you only deleted filenames.

Comment: When I run either of these commands, `logfile.txt` still gets deleted, unless if was already non-empty before the `find` starts.